# Validacion de la Curp en sat

Tags: php, javascript, webservice, post

Alguien sabe de un webservice o como hacer post para validar si es correcto el *curp*? o en su defecto obtener toda la informacion del *curp*?

Buscando por internet me he encontrado con esto

```
http://consultas.curp.gob.mx/CurpSP/curp1.do?strCurp=' . $curp . '&strTipo=B')
```

haciendo un post asi , pero solo me muestra `Invalid path /curp1` was requested

lo hago mediante Postman y es la respuesta, si lo hago en php me llega la respuesta en blanco.

Comment: Tengo entendido que no existe un servicio OFICIAL tipo web-service o API para consulta de CURP, lo más que podrías hacer es una validación con expresiones regulares para validar su estructura, pero para comprobar que existe en la base de datos del RENAPO, pues hasta donde yo se, no lo hay

Comment: ¿Qué te interesa validar? ¿Si el **formato** es válido? ¿O si esa CURP corresponde a un ciudadano/residente?

Comment: Relacionado: [Cómo validar una CURP de México](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/31039/127)

Answer (score 3):

Encontré esta liga navegando, espero y te sirva.

https://github.com/Api-Mexico/Php-Curp,

Mira te adjunto un ejemplo en PHP de como consumir el Servicio Web:

```
<?php
$peticion = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:ValidateMexico">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:Curp soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
     <return xsi:type="urn:CurpReq">
        <user xsi:type="xsd:string">prueba</user>
        <password xsi:type="xsd:string">sC}9pW1Q]c</password>
        <Curp xsi:type="xsd:string">LOOA531113HTCPBN07</Curp>
     </return>
      </urn:Curp>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>';
    $header = array(
        'Content-type: text/xml;charset="utf-8"',
        'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
        'SOAPAction: "urn:ValidateMexico#Curp"',
        'Connection: Keep-Alive',
        'Content-length: '.strlen($peticion),
    );
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://conectame2.ddns.net/ws/index.php');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $peticion);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, $peticion);
    $re = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$doom = new \DOMDocument();
$doom->loadXML($re);
$estatus = $doom->getElementsByTagName('Response')->item(0)->nodeValue;
if ($estatus=='correct') {
        echo 'Curp: '.  $doom->getElementsByTagName('Curp')->item(0)->nodeValue ."<br/>";
        echo 'Paterno: '.$doom->getElementsByTagName('Paterno')->item(0)->nodeValue."<br/>";
        echo 'Materno: '.$doom->getElementsByTagName('Materno')->item(0)->nodeValue."<br/>";
        echo 'Nombre: '.$doom->getElementsByTagName('Nombre')->item(0)->nodeValue."<br/>";
}else{
    echo "Error";
}
```

?>

Comment: Para que tu respuesta sea mejor recibida lee [answer], según los consejos edita la pregunta y explicalá más

Comment: Entendido, gracias!

Comment: Ese web service es oficial?

Comment: hace consultas sobre una base de datos oficial

Comment: Ese url al parecer ya no funciona pero puedes conseguir un API de la RENAPO acá: https://rapidapi.com/acrogenesis/api/curp-renapo

Comment: Acabo de probar la url y sigue funcionando, saludos

Answer (score 1):

Una API REST para validar CURP y obtener información básica de la persona. La API es Gratis (peticiones ilimitadas), Rápida (latencia de 200 ms en promedio) y Estandarizada  de acuerdo a ISO. [Más información usando Postman](https://x.sanchezcarlosjr.com/curp-renapo-api)

Ejemplo de petición:

```
GET https://domain.com/api/curp/CAHF620818HMNLNL09?apiKey=bpT32rai
```

Ejemplo de respuesta exitosa:

```
{
    "curp": "CAHF620818HMNLNL09",
    "fatherName": "CALDERON",
    "motherName": "HINOJOSA",
    "name": "FELIPE DE JESUS",
    "gender": "1",
    "birthday": "1962-01-01T00:08:00.000Z",
    "birthState": "MX-MIC"
}
```

[Documentación](https://x.sanchezcarlosjr.com/curp-renapo-api)

Answer (score 0):

Existe el webservice de [nubarium.com](http://nubarium.com), el cual funciona con REST.
Tiene un costo pero es muy económico.
Básicamente le mandas un JSON con la siguiente forma:

```
{
   "curp" : "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
}
```

Y te devuelve toda la información de la curp, incluyendo el PDF.